# Role-based declarative security for C#

Tags: java, c#, domain-driven-design, entity-framework, aspect-oriented

According to Domain [Driven Design and Development In Practice](https://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-in-practice):

> [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) (a sub-project in Spring Portfolio) provides a
>   fine-grained access control in both presentation (URL based) and
>   domain (Method Level) layers of the application. The framework uses
>   Spring's Bean Proxy to intercept method invocation and apply security
>   constraints. It offers a role-based declarative security for Java
>   objects using MethodSecurityInterceptor class. There is also instance
>   level security in the form of Access Control Lists (ACL's) for domain
>   objects to control the user access at the instance level.
>
> The main advantage of using Spring Security for managing the
>   authorization requirements in the domain model is that the framework
>   has a non-invasive architecture so we can have a clean separation
>   between the domain and security aspects. Also, the business objects
>   are not cluttered with security implementation details. We can write
>   common security rules in one place and apply them (using AOP
>   techniques) wherever they need to be implemented.

---

My question is:

**Is there a project like `Spring Security` for C# to help me writing common security rules in one place and apply them (using AOP techniques) wherever I need to be implemented.?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15419279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the URL level there is the [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd460317(v=vs.118))

For general methods there is [PostSharp](http://samples.postsharp.net/f/PostSharp.Samples.Authorization/)

But I would say that applying authorisation rules in this way to the domain layer and AOP in general are somewhat frowned upon these days.

There is also [Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html)

Comment: Why is AOP frowned upon exactly?

Comment: I think because it can couple your various classes too tightly. say I label up myobject with serialisation attributes and authorisation attributes etc now they are tightly coupled, where if I instead pass it to a SerialiserService or implement ISerializable I can have loose coupling.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Decorating classes or methods with AOP attributes does not necessarily force the developer to couple them at all. I have used AOP (with Postsharp) for many projects without any problems. You can use them for tracing, logging, method result caching and of course authorization.

However, I should also mention that using AOP for adding an ISerializable interface is not within the supported use cases of AOP (at least Postsharp). That I would consider a hack: http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/questions/573-aop-for-object-serialization

Comment: @VeyselÖzdemir are you saying that i can use Pserializable without referencing PostSharp.Serialization.PSerializableAttribute ?

Comment: Are you saying that you can use `ISerializable` without referencing `System.Runtime.Serialization`?

Comment: no, the 'approved' approach would be MySerialiser.Serialise(MyClass class) to avoid coupling the class

Comment: Like Newtonsoft.Json's approach.  But if you can do that, why ever bother with `ISerializable`?

Comment: Indeed. I don't think I suggested it. Its just my impression from reading around that AOP is frowned upon. I remember back in the day there a time where AOP auth and logging frameworks were all the rage and it would be suggested that you add them to all of your code for 'security'. nowadays the same approach seems to be confined to limited scopes such as the MVC controllers or ORMs. In relation to my memory of those times I would say it is now 'frowned upon'

Comment: I have applied `AuthorizeAttribute` to my command and query classes (in a CQRS-style application) and have the command/query dispatcher validate them.

Comment: @Evan if i code as MySerializer.Serialize(MyClass instance) then it means MySerializer is aware of MyClass, in oter words they are coupled. I would suggest MySerializer.Serialize(IMySerializable instance) and have MyClass implement IMySerializable so that they would not need to be aware of each other. However serialization is an extreme case to force the serialized classes to have specific qualities. Logging, caching and tracing are more transparent examples for AOP.

Comment: @VeyselÖzdemir theres no problem with the serialiser knowing about myclass, that's its job. The problem is when your classes know about serialising, logging, caching etc etc

Comment: @Evan I think we are talking about different things now. The scenario you mention is not about coupling rather about where you want to do the job. You can wrap your method and trace in one place or wrap everywhere that method is called and trace in million places. Then your whole system will know about (be coupled to) MyTracer.Trace(). Its a matter of taste but handling cross cutting concerns in a single place is not something to frown upon.

Comment: @VeyselÖzdemir no i think you are wrong.

Comment: @Evan yes i think i am in a different way ;)